# How to readdir in ../ on lighttpd? Permissions?

Tags: php, lighttpd

I'm trying to read all folder names and create buttons out of it via .php. It somehow doesn't work how I want it to work.

Foldernames to read are in /www/templates/

.php file is in /www/php/

tried to:
put `read.php` in `/www/templates/`, telling it to `opendir()` and `readdir()` of "./" and include it to `/www/php/` -> shown me results (folders) of `/www/php/` (where it works perfectly and shows the folders of "./" if it's placed in there aswell).
Tried using the complete path ( `/opt/xyz/www/templates/` ) -> no result at all

CHMOD of the folders are 766 - owner is the same as the PHP script.

Script placed in /www/php/:

```
<?php
$d = opendir('../templates/');
while(false !== ($f = readdir($d))) {
if (is_dir($f) && $f != "." && $f != "..") {
echo "<form action=\"./change.php\" method=\"get\">
<input type=\"submit\" name=\"template\" value=\"" . $f . "\"><br>";
}
}
?>
```

Script tried in /www/templates/:

```
<?php
$d = opendir('./');
while(false !== ($f = readdir($d))) {
[insert-code-from-above-here] }
?>
```

included the script in /www/templates/ to the "index.php" with:

```
<?php include('../templates/read.php'); ?>
```

Webserver: lighttpd

Comment: try getcwd()."../......" instead "../....."

Comment: Warning: opendir(/opt/xyz/www/php../templates/): failed to open dir: No such file or directory in /opt/xyz/www/php/test.php on line 2
Warning: readdir() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in /opt/xyz/www/php/test.php

Comment: sorry getcwd()."/../...."

Comment: Result is an empty page =/

Comment: if you have an empty page, it means that there is an error. check your error log to see what error you have

Comment: (server.c.968) WARNING: unknown config-key: url.access-deny (ignored)
Is the only error from error.log, doubt it has to do with it, but not sure

Comment: SOLVED -> problem has been: if (is_dir($f) had to be if (is_dir('../templates/' . $f)

Comment: That code is sub-optimal because it judges each filesystem item in your script. I'd use something like `ls -1F` or `ls -1Fl` (with permissions) to populate an array, then do the processing. Also lose that `<form...` thing, making simple hyperlinks with `<a...` works easier. Plus you get the sorting bells and whistles for free with `ls`.